# PHP functions - Security issues?

Tags: php, shell-exec, passthru

I have a question regarding the following PHP functions:

```
exec()

system()

passthru()

shell_exec()
```

I've tried signing up with https://wpengine.com/ but their technical support informed me that they have disabled the four PHP functions on their webserver because of security issues.

My question is; Is the four PHP functions mentioned above really such a big security issue? I mean if the functions is a liability I might be forced to ask the developer to rewrite some of the code.

Best regards

Comment: Yes, they are - do ask the developers to find other solutions.

Comment: That’s stuff you would rather use on your own dedicated server, but not in a shared hosting environment.

Comment: These functions might represent a security issue if they the plugin passes unescaped user variables inside them, an obvious example would be exec($_POST['command'])

Comment: You'll need your own server or virtual server. It unlikely that you'll find a shared host that will allow this.

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you for the support. I'll ask the developer what to do. Have a nice day. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, its a security issue.

E.g.

```
system("rm -rf ~/*")
```